# CDash client setup

Tags: continuous-integration, cmake, cdash

I'm trying to create a C++ CI environment by using CDash.

I've got CDash running on my computer and I can send some results to it from the CDash clients, by running the ctest manually.

I'm a bit lost on how to setup a client to automatically compile and test the code when the source code changes in the version control system (subversion), or at specific times.

I have the Mastering CMake book, but it doesn't seem to say much on that topic.

Is there any way to do the continuous build without hacking around with scheduled tasks / cron?

Is there any good example that would be useful to check out?

Can I somehow order to run a build on some site from the Dashboard? I kinda remember seeing this somewhere but I'm unable to find it now.

Is CDash any good for CI environments?  (use comments to answer this one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CDas@Home](http://www.kitware.com/products/html/TheCDashHomeCloud.html) might be the solution. Generally I have my continuous machines run a script on a nightly cron job that polls the repository every couple of minutes for ~24 hours.

Comment: I did something similar. Thanks. This seems to be implemented in 1.8.2